Install Builder - Linux - Run at startup
I created an installer using Install Builder on Debian.
This installer installs an application. How to make this application run at computer boot up on Debian Linux from Install Builder installer?

In Linux, setting an application to run at startup typically involves adding a .desktop file to the appropriate autostart directory. Here's how you can do it:

Create a .desktop File:
Create a .desktop file for your application. This file contains information about the application, including the command to run it. Here's an example:
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=My Application
Exec=/path/to/your/application

Replace /path/to/your/application with the actual path to your application executable.

Save the .desktop File:
Save the .desktop file with a .desktop extension (e.g., myapplication.desktop).

Move the File to the Autostart Directory:
Move the .desktop file to one of the autostart directories depending on your Linux distribution:

Global Autostart Directory: /etc/xdg/autostart/
User-Specific Autostart Directory: $HOME/.config/autostart/

For example, to add the .desktop file for all users, you would move it to /etc/xdg/autostart/. You'll likely need root privileges (sudo) to do this.

Test the Startup Behavior:
Reboot your system or log out and log back in to test if your application starts automatically at startup.


This method works across various Linux desktop environments such as GNOME, KDE, Xfce, etc. The .desktop file format is a standard way to define application launchers in Linux desktop environments.
Source: ChatGPT
